# Meshlab- Is there a easy way to set may coordinates system in reference to a single point?

Tags: meshlab, openfoam

I am using meshlab to update two stl files which a later use in a CFD software(openfoam). Now I have to change mine coordinate systems of both stl files which I would like to set in according to a point of the stl files. I know there should be a easy way to achieve that, but did not manage to find it so far....

Thanks for you help;)

Comment: Do you need to align (rotate and translate) the files or just make that point to have same coordinate in both files?

Comment: I need to have one edge of the stl file exactly at the origin of the coordinate system